# Windows phone 8.1 proximity device stop answering after lock screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, nfc

I have exactly same problem as described here in this post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/331b9a6a-02ce-44d6-839b-0c18acccaf89/no-nfc-events-after-lockscreen?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK

Error appears on 8.1 devices, earlier versions work fine. So when running app in 8.1 device it works fine until you lock the screen. After resuming proximity device just stops launching events.

Does anyone know solution to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we found the answer to this problem.

Seems like there is some kind of error with registering proximity device to application after locking screen. So what worked for us is quite ugly coding, but works as hot fix:

```
if (device!= null)
{
            device.StopSubscribingForMessage(id);
            device= null;

            GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
}

device= ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
id = device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", ReceivedHandler);
```

Solution here is to force garbage collection and register device again.

Comment: Where you put this solution??  I have the same issue when phone was keep idle for 5-10 minutes and start scan NFC. It will not read a data.